# Nodeport is not sending the traffic to service port in GKE private cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cluster, service, kubernetes

I have a private cluster created in GKE and gitlab is running as a pod in this cluster.
Here, nodeport is not sending the traffic to service port and hence unable to push images to gitlab.

Error response from daemon: Get http://localhost:32121/v2/: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting

Can we connect to private docker repo using localhost from within a private cluster.

Comment: Could you share more info about your environment? Services and pods might be helpful.

Comment: Gitlab pod is running on the cluster as LoadBalancer service.
CLUSTER-IP:10.28.0.129
External-IP 104.154.84.33
Port: 80:30539/TCP,8085:31685/TCP,222:30716/TCP,8223:32121/TCP

The commands and the errors are below:

sudo docker login -u xxxx -p xxxx localhost:32121
--"Error response from daemon: Get http://localhost:32121/v2/: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:32121: connect: connection refused"

Comment: sudo docker login -u xxxx -p xxxx 104.154.84.33:32121


--WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get https://104.154.84.33:32121/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Comment: Did you follow this link? https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/

Comment: Yes, we had tried this, but ended up with the same error, ever after restarting docker.

Comment: can you share output from `kubectl get svc`? If your services are create in different namespace please include it.